# React children props are always equal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was trying to implement an ErrorBoundary HoC component for error handling as per [React16 Doc](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html). I made the ErrorBoundary component as PureComponent and I noticed that the **children** props are always equal and it tried to prevent the re-rendering of the child components.

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.PureComponent {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
}

componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
}

render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
        return <PageNotFound />;
    }
    return this.props.children;
} }
```

After modifying the component to React.Component and added a componentDidUpdate, I was able to see that the children props are always equal.

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
    if(this.props.children === nextProps.children){ //returns TRUE
        console.log('children value are equal')
    }
}
```

The below code shows how I used the ErrorBoundary Component

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <ErrorBoundary>
        <Route path='/' component={Router} />
    </ErrorBoundary>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Can anyone explain how the children prop is equal?

Comment: Not sure what is your question. `ErrorBoundary` in provided code always have the same child, i.e. `Route` ?

Answer (score 0):

`children` always refers to values that were passed as component children, i.e. `<Route>` React element:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <Route path='/' component={Router} />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Since parent component didn't rerender, `<Route>` object is the same.